# How can I add an ActionListener or DataChangedListener for PickerComponent

Tags: codenameone

I have a PickerComponent in my form. I need to have actions triggered when a new date is picked - for instance value of other components will change. I cannot find any ActionListener or DataChangedListener. What should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. getPicker().addActionListener ...